# Event Tracking Using Google Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics

I have seen other topics on this issue. I have tried to search and cant figure it out so i need help.

My tracking code is...

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-41800392-1', 'monsourlawfirm.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

and the event is a click to call on the site. the code for that is...

```
<a href="tel:8882594979" onClick="ga('send', 'mobile', 'click to call', '888-259-4979');">1 (888) 259-4979</a>
```

I have waited 24hrs and do not see anything recording.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're missing the hit type parameter. Check out [Universal Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). Your event should be:

```
<a href="tel:8882594979" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'mobile', 'click to call', '888-259-4979');">1 (888) 259-4979</a>
```

You can verify that the event is firing using a tool to monitor http requests or by logging into your GA account and looking at real-time reports.

Comment: I can see the event firing in the Real-Time>Events. It worked. Now just need to wait and see if it passes it down to Behavior>Events. I'd give you an up vote but I'm a newbie and can't.

Comment: If you want to check the GA custom events, and you're using Chrome browser, download an extension from Google called GA Debugger.  It shows you everything Google Analytics is doing on a page including firing of custom events.

Comment: Always provide a link... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en